# expecting colon, found ERROR MESSAGE after running test class

Tags: apex, unit-test

I am trying to cover some lines in my controller apex class, but since hours dealing with the error message:

```
Expecting colon, found 'TestPostgrado1'.
```

The method I am trying to cover through my controller test class is this (method in my controller):

```
public list<Product2> getProgramsFromListId(String listId){
list<Product2> listProgramas = new list<Product2>();
String query = 'Select Id, Name from Product2 where Id In ' + listId ; 
listProgramas = Database.query(query);
return listProgramas;
}
```

In order to cover that part I have written these lines in my code on the controller test class:

```
Product2 postgrado1 =  new Product2(Name = 'TestPostgrad1');
insert postgrado1;

Product2 postgrado2 =  new Product2(Name = 'TestPostgrad2');
insert postgrado2;

List<Product2> postgrados = new List<Product2> ();
postgrados.add(postgrado1);
postgrados.add(postgrado2);

    //List<Product2> listProgramas = new list<Product2>();
    //listProgramas.add(postgrado.Name);

controller.getProgramsFromListName(postgrado1.Name);
```

ok, I know postgrado1.Name is not correct, I was trying with several variants, but nothing happens, the errors is still being displayed.
I tend to think that it has to do with the "IN" in the SELECT statement in the controller method,

Does anybody know, what I am doing wrong or what is missing in the lines in my test class?. The errors are pointing to the line

```
controller.getProgramsFromListName(postgrado1.Name);
```

in my controller test class.

and to the line

```
listProgramas = Database.query(query);
```

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

You are on right track. `IN` operator is usually used for filtering over collections like `Set` or `List` in SOQL.

In your example, you can try any of the following:

```
// Enclosing in single quotes
String query = 'SELECT Id, Name FROM Product2 WHERE Id = \'' + listId + '\'';
```

OR

```
// Cleaner one, using a colon
String query = 'SELECT Id, Name FROM Product2 WHERE Id = :listId';
```

Refer [Dynamic SOQL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_soql.htm) document for more details.

Comment: I don't think that first approach will work.

Comment: Ah you're right, need to enclose it in single quotes. I had not used that one in quite sometime, thanks.

Comment: My understanding was it is a `List` variable. I think you need `String.join` and some parens here.

Comment: From the code it looks like a string variable, `getProgramsFromListId(String listId)`

Comment: Thanks Rahul, I tried it with getProgramsFromListName instead, because while using getProgramsFromListId instead, I get the error "Invalid Id field'. What worked for me was:

Comment: @AdrianLarson, You were right, I was unable to understand the question properly.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was:

```
Product2 postgrado1 =  new Product2(Name = 'TestPostgrad1');
    insert postgrado1;
    Product2 postgrado2 =  new Product2(Name = 'TestPostgrad2');
    insert postgrado2;

    String query_str = '(\'';  
    query_str +=  + postgrado1 + '\',\'' + postgrado2 + '\'';
    query_str += ')';

    controller.getProgramsFromListName(query_str);
```

Comment: `getProgramsFromListId(String listId)` to `getProgramsFromListId(List<String> listId)`, better would be to use a list